# android download the image from url store in internal memory then display that image in imageview

Tags: android, android-image, android-internal-storage

I want to download the image from url and store it to internal memory after storing get the image stored in internal memory and display it in imageview

Comment: What you have try ?

Comment: i need to display an image in imageview but first i need to download the image from url and store it to internal memory after that get the image stored in internal memory and display it in imageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to download the image

```
  URL url = new URL(<your url>);
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  int n = in.read(buf);
 while (n!=-1)
 {
  out.write(buf, 0, n);
   n=in.read(buf)
  }
 out.close();
 in.close();
 byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
```

And below code to save it to internal storage

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  fos.write(response);
  fos.close();
```

where file path for internal storage is

```
  String filePath=getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + "image_" + <some unique identifier like int or string that is different for different images>
```

ANd to show in imageView use

```
  File imgFile = new  File(filePath);

if(imgFile.exists()){

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

 }
```

Hope it helps.